# VueJs: How to convert a render function to JSX code equivalent or template file (.vue file)

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, jsx

Is there a tool for converting a render functions created in vueJs to the equivalent JSX code ?

I only have found tools for transpiling JSX code to javascript code (using the render function)

I already have the minified files created with babel and i don't have the original source code.
When i unminified the javascript code i notice that the vue template file are like render functions, but its very difficult to maintenance or adding new functionality.

The other approach would be to creating the source code again, but this is going to be my last option.